# Repetitive documentation in JSDoc for subclasses implementing abstract methods?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

The JSDoc [documentation for `@abstract`](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-abstract.html) shows separate documentation blocks for the (abstract) superclass function and the subclass implementation.  I can see where this could be useful in some cases but a lot of the time your subclass function description should be the same as the abstract parent -- `getArea()` gets an area whether this is a Circle, Square, Rectangle, whatever.

Is there any kind of shorthand or established pattern to write documentation once and have it apply to overridden abstract functions at all levels?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any shorthand or established pattern for documentation. You might be able to utilize shorthand depending on your text editor but other than that I don't think so. What text editor are you using?

Comment: I'm using VS Code but I was hoping for something that would be part of the core JSDoc spec -- my first concern is Intellisense but I'd like something that will also work with a static doc generator.  If I have to duplicate by hand then I guess I'm stuck with it, I'm just surprised that there isn't a better way.